# Hostedservice with events

Tags: c#, ihostedservice

I have a question, i'm making a disk monitoring tool, just the simple system.io.filesystemwatcher currently and i'm stuck on the 'always running part'.

So I tought, I create a watchservice that subscribes on all the events of the filesystemwatcher. whenever one of the evnts hits (created,renamed,deleted,modified) I simply put the filename onto a queue and then every 30ish seconds it get send to the api.

Why -> because for each disk all the events will produce a lot of events from the filesystemwatcher.

Now in the past I already have implemnted this in a winforms application and of course as long as the winforms application runs so will the filesystemwatche.

however, I currently want it to run as a windows service, so I tought it would be the best option to go with the IHostedService.

Now I seem to be stuck on the fact that in the startasync you create an instance of the watchservice(the one included with the filesystemwatcher), but obviously i don't want to return as the application wil stop and or don't want to use the while loop that checks the canncelationtoken because it would created instance.

currently this is my histedservice implementation:

```
public class FileAgentService : IHostedService
    {     
        private QueueService queueService;
        private bool isStarted = false;

        public FileAgentService(QueueService queueService)
        {
            this.queueService = queueService;
        }

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var disks = DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(x => x.IsReady == true);            
            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                if (!isStarted)
                {
                    isStarted = true;
                    foreach (var disk in disks)
                    {
                        WatchService service = new(disk.Name, queueService);
                    }
                }                
            }     
            
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

So for each disk it creates an instance of my service, however it doesn't seem to pickup any events from the filesystemwatcher, so I think i'm doing something wrong here,

The windows service needs to start create an instance of the service for each disk and then just keep running and picking up events.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: a.) Normally you implement BackgroundService not IHostedService direct b.) Waiting for IsCancellationRequested in a loop isn't uncommon. But your way is somewhat weird why not create your WatchService(s) and afterwards having a while loop waiting for the cancelling with a Task.Delay inside? c.) How about some logging in your code that might help finding the problem? For example could be that your service runs under an account that isn't allowed to the see all or any drives.

Comment: well good question in a winform application as long that the application run there is an instance of the filesystemwatcher, and that is what i'm trying to achieve in a windows service, or console application, I could create the instances if that is what you mean but somehow i still need the for loop for each disk start a new instance.

Comment: Then just create the WatchService(s), start them and put them in a list so they are  referenced and won't be garbage collected. And afterwards wait for the cancellationToken in an independent while loop. `while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) await Task.Delay(2000, cancellationToken);`

Comment: Oke And I assume  put the list in the while loop aswell?.

Comment: Oke And I assume  put the list in the while loop aswell?.

Comment: Why should they? Your WatchService should do something constantly on its own or doesn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249288/discussion-between-technology-researcher-and-ralf).